# Refresh of screens on backgrounding and foregrounding an application

Tags: java, android, background, foreground

I am working on an Android app with multiple activities. When moving from one activity to another in certain cases I want to refresh the display but not in others. 
One case is where I background the application and foreground it again. When I foreground it, I want to refresh everything on the screen depending on which activity
I backgrounded to begin with. How can I do this? I am unfortunately a bit new to Android so some appropriate basics where applicable would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

You can use onSaveInstanceState() to save information before onPause() is called. In onResume() you can use the saved info as a case in a switch statement or some conditional to refresh what you want.

Comment: I think I am not understanding very well. So here are three scenarios. I start on a MainActivity screen.
1) I background the app.
2) I click on a button on MainActivity that takes me to Activity2.
3) I click on a button on MainActivity that takes me to Activity3.

So how can I distinguish between these three situations in onSaveInstanceState()? I presume onSaveInstanceState() is called in each case but there is no way to tell
which activity (1,2, or 3) is getting launched next right?